# How to use NHibernate and protect some table's data?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In a new project I created my class let's say ProductSpecialGroup :

```
ProductSpecialGroup 
- string Name
- IList<Product> Products
```

In this project I had to create also the mapping for the Product table that already exists and is used by many more project.

Is there any way to tell to nhibernate : don't touch this table, don't update/delete it, just select from it ? Or at least what are the configuration( with cascade I think) that I need to check to be sure that a myProductSpecialgroup.Products.Clear() won't create a disaster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set "mutable" = false in the table mapping it will treat it as read-only.  Also to be sure you can set the cascade from the parent to "none"

Comment: I didn't knwo about it, thanks. About the cascade : what about the many to many relationship, If cascade is None will it save the relationship ?

Comment: It will not, so if that is the case, go ahead and allow the cascade.  As long as the table mapping is mutable false you are safe.  The cascade none is just an extra precaution.

Comment: Also on the cascade - Set it to "All".  All will delete the relationship but not the other side of the many-many.  In contrast, cascade of "all-delete-orphan" will also delete the other side of the many-many if it has become an orphan (has no other relationships).

Comment: Ok thanks, it might be an other question, but in a many to many relationship is there any way to say "just handle the relation not the related entities content" ?

Comment: That's basically what "All" will do.  It will only impact the relationship, not the related entity in the many-many.

Answer (score 1):

Use mutable="false" and check the cascades as proposed by swannee. In addition to that, if it is that critical, consider using a view or consider to grant only read permissions to that table.